# Combined length of portions of a line segment

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory, continuity, rigid-transformation

Suppose I have a continuous function $f : X \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$) that is piecewise rigid, i.e. $X$ has a finite partition $\mathcal{P}$ such that for all $P \in \mathcal{P}$, $f|_P$ is the restriction of a rigid transformation $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. I'm trying to prove that $f$ preserves the length of geodesics (line segments), but are the above conditions sufficient?

Here is my approach: given a line segment $L \subseteq X$, $\mathcal{L} = \{P \cap L\ |\ P \in \mathcal{P}, P \cap L \neq \emptyset\}$ is a finite partition of $L$. $f$ must map each element of $\mathcal{L}$ isometrically, so the combined length of that element is preserved. Hence,
$$\begin{align}
(\text{length of }f(L)) &= \sum_{L' \in \mathcal{L}}f|_{L'}(\text{combined length of }L')\\
                        &= \sum_{L' \in \mathcal{L}}(\text{combined length of }L')\\
                        &= (\text{length of }L).
\end{align}$$

How do I make this argument rigorous? Do I need measure theory? The problem is that each $L'$ has many connected components; it is entirely possible for me to restrict $f$ such that each $L'$ has a finite number of connected components, but I would like to avoid that as much as possible - because that assumption would actually be a consequence of what I'm trying to prove!

Comment: Do you mean $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ instead of $X$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.